# Cakephp 2 use task in another task

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

In a relatively big shell I am using a few tasks, however it appeared a necessity to use some functions of one task (lets call it a main task) in another tasks as well.

So, how I can use a task in another task. Cakephp 2.x

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Shell::$tasks` property to define the additional tasks that your task should load, or load them manually using `TaskCollection::load()`, avaiable via the `Shell::$Tasks` property.

The additional tasks can be accessed via magic properties using the task names.

```
class SubTask extends AppShell
{
    public $tasks = array(
        'Main'
    );

    // ...

    public function subMethod()
    {
        $this->Main->mainMethod();

        $this->Tasks->load('Other');
        $this->Other->otherMethod();
    }

    // ...
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > Shell tasks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#shell-tasks)**
- **[Cookbook > Shells, Tasks & Console Tools > Shell API > Shell::$tasks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#Shell::$tasks)**
- **[API > Shell::$Tasks](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-Shell.html#$Tasks)**
- **[API > TaskCollection.html::load()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-TaskCollection.html#_load)**